# Why do I do AcceptChanges() after adding rows in C# DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net

```
DataTable() table = new DataTable();
table.Rows.Add(DataRow);
table.AcceptChanges();
```

When you add a row, the data is automatically entered,
and why do you AcceptChanges() additionally?

Comment: You need justo to read the official doc

Comment: Honestly, a better question might be "why are you using DataTable?" - that was useful for transitioning from ADO RecordSet, but that was a *looong* time ago now, and usually ***literally any other mechanism*** would be preferred. But: DataTable does some basic change / delta tracking; this simply marks the data as "unchanged", so *additional* edits can be tracked. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges

Comment: @alessandro problem is : official documentation sucks.

Comment: @MarcGravell : there are still use cases for ADO.Net : https://blog.devart.com/ado-net-vs-entity-framework.html

Answer (score -1):

Commits all the changes made to this table since the last time `AcceptChanges()` was called.

More on the topic here: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges?view=net-5.0)